# Connection between Front-End(React JS) to Back-End(C++)

Tags: c++, reactjs, connection, frontend, backend

My project is build from two sections, **Front-End** that is built using ***React JS (Website)***, and the **Back-End** built using ***C++***(because I work with huge files and I need to execute the algorithm very fast.
So I need to connect between these two section.
How I can I do that ?
***What is the technique to connect React JS with C++.***
Thank you .

Comment: The backend provides the frontend data. The frontend usually is interpreted and executed on the client's machine. The backend is executed on the server. What do you mean with _connect_?

Comment: Exactly! I mean, how I can pass the data from the client's machine to the server.
What is the tool that I can use to send the data from the client's side to server and vice versa.

Comment: Your server needs an API, e.g. REST. The client uses AJAX to call the API.